# change placeholder colour antdesign datepicker

Tags: antd, placeholder

How can I change ant design date picker placeholder color? I couldn't find CSS for placeholders color

https://ant.design/components/date-picker/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, you can try the next selector for it:

```css
.ant-picker-input>input::placeholder {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this from Javascript/Typescript?

Comment: I don't know this way